# Share existing facebook post (thus incrementing 'Shares' count of original post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hei,

I have an app in which i'm trying to share existing facebook public content from an account (like a link of a photo) to my wall using Facebook PHP SDK, with a call to 'graph.facebook.com/me/feed' and using the original 'link' attribute of the post which looks like this:
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=XXXXXXX&set=a.XXXX.XX.XXXXXX&type=1&relevant_count=1

The result is a post which says 'Alex Shared XXX's photo'
And a preview of the photo appears, but the original post's 'Shares' doesn't get incremented nor does it show the Share i did through the call there.

Is it possible to fix that at all? if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niraj Shah is right there is no way to reshare a post.

But there is a loophole since you can reshare photo posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16294769/441907

Comment: Thanks Nick, and Niraj, I've been playing a lot with this and already had a look at the question you've referred (as well as gave up trying to do it until further possible updates to facebook API itself).

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to reshare a existing post using the API or PHP SDK. The only thing you can do is create a copy of the share and publish it, but it won't increment the original share count as you've already found.

Comment: Seems so, I've done tons of testing and so far can't get it to work except with new post!