# How to reshare a Facebook Post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to reshare a facebook post by letting my visitors go to some url and press share.

I looked into sharer.php and https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed but both seem to only give me ways to let a user share a link and not reshare a facebook post.

I don't want to simple post the content of a post but to repost it, so the share count of the post also goes up.

Did i miss something, and is there a way to accomplish resharing via some api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Crissc Reinberger is right that i can't reshare a post in a way that increments the share count.

Still there is a way to reshare a post that is a photo which increments the share count of the photo post:

- Post an image
- Get the Image link:

  e.g.: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152377142043306
- Take the url and add it to sharer.php:

  e.g.: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152377142043306

This way you will really reshare the image and also increment the share count of the image post.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a post where someone was trying to do the same, unfortunately this is not possible with current API. You can only get the Post (with the post ID, if is public or with access token), scrape the information and create a new one.

Comment: It is possible - see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Facebook wont let you rehsrae their photo.

But using a proxy you can do that. And proxy gives you the flexibility to choose between sharer, or feed dialog.

Feed dialog fits better mobile web apps. Faster amd have better UI. Sharer **don`t exist** on mobile web apps.

https://images.weserv.nl/ does the job. Facebook accept the image as a picture param, and this way you are able to reshare thier posts.

Usage example (plus width and hight to improve performance)

```
'https://images.weserv.nl/?url=' + facebookImageUrl + '&h=200&w=200'
```