# FB.UI Feed Dialog - cannot "share" a facebook's picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Sharing facebook photo (really a facebook photo) using mobile web app & Feed Dialog.

**The problem:** *Cannot send facebook's photo to the Feed Dialog.*

All code works great. I get all properties as they sent to the function.

```
    FB.ui
        method: "feed"
        link: 'url'
        app_id: myAppID
        name: 'photo's name'
        description: ''
        caption: $('#albumName').text()
        picture: 'http://myUrl.com/logo.png'

    , (response) ->
        if response and response.post_id
            console.log 'Photo was shared'
        else
            console.log 'Photo was not shared. Please try again'
```

If I place a **static** photo, to represent the [Picture parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#params), all goes fine, **But** if I try to call **a facebook picture** I try to share, then I get a 500 server error.

> GET
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?access_token=...662390597_s.jpg&sdk=joey
>   500 (OK)

This is totally bizarre. The URL that goes to the dialog iframe, goes with all the needed parameters, including access_token.

It seems like a design issue. Like someone in facebook don't want us to pretend to be facebook when we customly share things using their feed dialog, when we share facebook photos.

Am I right?

*** Problem Solved. See my answer below ***

Comment: Might this be an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929025/how-to-reshare-a-facebook-post/16294769#16294769

Comment: @DrColossos See my answer below. Proxy solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**!!! *Problem Solved* !!!**

Facebook don't accept their own CDN as a source. We need to bypass that in order to share, therefore we can reshare a facebook the photo using a proxy.

**http://images.weserv.nl** does the job. Facebook accept the image as a picture param, and this way you are able to reshare their posts.

Usage example (plus width and hight to improve performance)

```
'https://images.weserv.nl/?url=' + facebookImageUrl + '&h=200&w=200'
```

Answer (score 0):

I  can't  share facebook photo use this example 
when i  share  with (fb.ui  method feed) i get  404 error on this link

```
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=460125687444228&v=1&size=z&cksum=047536ba625482c9b5343f2eb94a7039&src=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.weserv.nl%2F%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ffbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net%252Fhphotos-ak-ash4%252Ft1.0-9%252F10157304_1383818341898181_8685912667835736794_n.jpg%26h%3D200%26w%3D200"

"app=460125687444228
cksum=047536ba625482c9b5343f2eb94a7039
size=z
src=https://images.weserv.nl/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash4%2Ft1.0-9%2F10157304_1383818341898181_8685912667835736794_n.jpg&h=200&w=200
v=1"
```

Where my error ?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle demo for that? if the FB Url working under your login context, therefore it suppose to work.

Comment: i cant create demo on jsfiddle but i can show  this in my test application 
http://i60.tinypic.com/2luoz1u.png
https://apps.facebook.com/testaburuslanbat/ http://i59.tinypic.com/14ihkr9.png
p.s. Sorry for my bad English